# mktextfm failed to make igo10.tfm

Tags: fonts, errors, packages, compiling

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and need to install the package at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/igo to compile a document I have received the tex source of.  I am trying to follow the instructions at http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2012/06/14/managing-latex-packages-manually-in-ubuntu-12-04 , but after unzipping the zip file downloaded from CTAN into ~/texmf/tex/latex , the font auto-generation does not seem to work properly.

Here's the excerpt from the compilation detailing the error:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
++++++++++++ igo.sty - January 2007 - 0.62 +++++++++++ 
+ A TeX package to manipulate Go games and positions + 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

(/home/kroon/texmf/tex/latex/igo/repeat.tex Loading loop macro, version 0.93)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm igo10
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input igo10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf igo10
! I can't find file `igo10'.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input igo10

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input igo10

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: igo10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input igo10' failed to make igo10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \igo@font=igo10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.175 \smallgoban

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on talk.log.
make: *** [talk.pdf] Error 1
```

Here's the relevant section of talk.log:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++ igo.sty - January 2007 - 0.62 +++++++++++
+ A TeX package to manipulate Go games and positions +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

(/home/kroon/texmf/tex/latex/igo/repeat.tex Loading loop macro, version 0.93
\REPdepth=\count350
)
\igo@count=\count351
\igo@endwhile=\count352
\igo@fontsize=\count353
\igo@minrow=\count354
\igo@maxrow=\count355
\igo@mincol=\count356
\igo@maxcol=\count357
\igo@box=\box98
\igo@dimen=\dimen315

! Font \igo@font=igo10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
                   \global
l.175 \smallgoban

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 33445 strings out of 495059
 754929 string characters out of 3182030
 852479 words of memory out of 3000000
 36022 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4245 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 50i,0n,74p,664b,609s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

missfont.log simply contains 13 lines all saying "mktextfm igo10".

Finally, mfput.log contains the following:

```
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (base=mf 2012.9.12)  14 NOV 2012 22:19
**\mode=ljfour; mag=1; nonstopmode; input igo10

! Emergency stop.
<*> \mode=ljfour; mag=1; nonstopmode; input igo10

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct path for local font sources on a TeX Live distribution either

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source/<package>
```

for a "all users" installation or, for a "personal" installation

```
~/texmf/fonts/source/<package>
```

or

```
~/Library/texmf/fonts/source/<package>
```

(for MacTeX installed TeX Live on Mac OS X).

In the first case a `maketexlsr` command must be issued (with appropriate privileges).

Just to be more specific, the complete path for `igo.mf` should be

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source/igo/igo.mf
```

or, for the personal tree, either

```
~/texmf/fonts/source/igo/igo.mf
```

or

```
~/Library/texmf/fonts/source/igo/igo.mf
```

depending on the platform.

The prefix for the TeX Live/Debian might be slightly different for system-wide installation, but the personal tree is in the same location (`~/texmf/`).

Don't use the `metafont` subtree for source files.

Comment: Thanks for the extra input.  I haven't checked your solution, though (since I got my issue resolved another way, and don't want to fiddle with it if it's not broken right now).

Answer (score 2):

For future people with this problem: the issue seems to have been that the font files included in the package are not detected when unzipped according to the blog instructions.  This is because `~/texmf/tex/` is in the search path for tex resources, but not for metafont resources (which the font files were).

To get them recognized, I ran `kpsepath mf |sed -e 's/:/\n/g'` , and found that   `~/texmf/metafont/` was in my path for metafont resources.  Moving the fonts into an appropriate subdirectory here caused them to be successfully detected.

Comment: Steve, thanks for troubleshooting this and sharing the comment on my blog!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Many errors when I ran LaTeX, like

```
mktextfm: failed to write
```

and

```
mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation, and on and on.
```

Finally inspired by this thread and the answers, I realized something was missing.

**Yum** what provides **TeXLive**, led me to install

> yum install texlive-6:2016-36.20160520.fc27.5.x86_64

and all errors went away, and LaTeX/TeX started functioning. This was on a new installation of **Fedora 2.7**